# Файлы UI фрагмента

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragment

Решил разобраться с фрагмента, создал через New project Navigation Drawer Activity. В каждом фрагменте создалось два файла UI: ...Fragment и ...ViewModel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём их различие? В одном понятно, отображение UI. Но для чего второй?

Comment: Второй видимо класс [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel?hl=hu) из JetPack. Это класс-прослойка между интерфейсом и данными. [Подробнее](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/527-urok-4-viewmodel.html) об этом.

Comment: Один вопрос должен содержать одну проблему. Если у вас несколько проблем - создайте несколько вопросов.

Comment: Разобрался с обоими, спасибо

Comment: Если вы самостоятельно нашли ответ на свой вопрос, напишите ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). Это поможет другим участникам с аналогичной проблемой быстрее решить ее.